# HP Notebook Pavilion g6-2101sl freeze

Tags: 12.04, freeze, hp-pavilion

I just bought this notebook and I've already installed in a new partition Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with 6GB of swap memory.

**UPDATE2:**

This is the laptop configuration: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=it&lc=it&dlc=it&tmp_geoLoc=true&docname=c03397517

Sometimes (without any special conditions) Ubuntu freezes.
My mouse is blocked, the UI is blocked, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to kill something or to restart is blocked, I can't really do anything...

I've also tried and it freezes with:

- Ubuntu 3D
- Ubuntu 2D
- GNOME Shell

and it freezes both with low and high load.

I can only press the power button (physically) and restart my laptop (and this is not the correct way to do things).
I'm using this laptop for work, so I need a stable OS without this freeze.

Someone knows how to solve this problem?

**UPDATE:**

- `/var/log/messages` is empty
- `/var/log/kernel.log` -> http://paste.ubuntu.com/1220182/
- `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` -> http://paste.ubuntu.com/1220186/

I just installed the proprietary driver from ATI, but it crashes anyway. This morning I started the laptop, I enabled wireless, opened Dropbox and Chrome -> freeze.

When it freezes I cannot:

- Do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get console access
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> + `r` to reload session
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> + `RESUB` to restart

It is totally frozen.

Comment: I'd suggest posting the system logs (/var/log/messages, /var/log/kern.log, /var/log/Xorg.0.log) using [paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com).

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes ?

Comment: @fossfreedom not really, since he wants to solve a particular problem with a particular machine. Maybe someone who has the same laptop will see the question and posts a specific reply.

Comment: @January updated with logs, hope it helps

Comment: Have you done any kernel updates recently ? Try different kernel version from "Previous Linux versions" in GRUB menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the solution is to upgrade the current kernel to version 3.x this seems to have solved my problem. 
In this [Article](http://partiallysanedeveloper.blogspot.it/2012/05/ivy-bridge-hd4000-linux-freeze.html) I understand that I've the same problem of that user (Ivy Bridge bug).

Steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/kernel
sudo apt-get update
```

For 32bit users

```
sudo apt-get install linux-kernel
```

For 64bit users

```
sudo apt-get install linux-kernel-64
```

Answer (score 2):

@StErMi, the errors below can be related to your problem.

```
[FIRMWARE BUG] ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS

[Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)

drm:intel_dsm_platform_mux_info] *ERROR* MUX INFO call failed
```

According to [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=709115#c36), using the `acpi_backlight=vendor` option will solve first bug. If this does not work, you can try the `acpi=noirq` option.

For the second bug, it is [recommended](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=732226#c5) to make a BIOS update and you can see that BIOS update solved the [problem](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=732226#c12).

For the third one, one [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/913272/comments/3) is to use the `pci=noapci` option, but if you use this option you will not be able to use the ATI graphics card.

I know these will not permanently solve your problem but at least there is hope that one of the workarounds could provide a usable Ubuntu for you.

To use the options that are mentioned here, look at [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions).

Comment: if those changes will fix my freeze, how can I share my solution in order to set by default those options in fresh installations? Anyway I will try to do as you said and I will update (and change as correct answer) in a few days of testing. Also, from Windows I launched HP Help that automatically update bios. Is it really updating bios or have I to do it manually?

Comment: As I said I'm using Ubuntu only to develop, so I don't need to have the ATI enabled, I think that integrated VGA can handle Unity3D animations right? So I can enable pci=noapc, am I correct?

Comment: acpi_backlight=vendor has not worked (it freezed again). Now I will try to use acpi=noirq. Have I to use both or only the latest?

Comment: also acpi=noirq wont solve the problem, it has just freezed :( now I'll try to add pci=noapci to grub config

Comment: Sorry, all those options have not solved my problem :(

Comment: Sorry for tha late answer and what I offer to "solve" the issue didn't solve it. I will search a suitable workaround.

Comment: I already solved my issue, please look at my accepted answer :)

Comment: I am glad you find a solution:)

Answer (score 1):

I had a random freeze problem with my new Lenovo T430s as well (i7-3520M). It was between once-a-week and 3-times-a-day.

Somewhere on the Internet I've found indications that this might be an Ivy Bridge graphics causing the freeze.

Then I updated to 12.10 alpha and problem has vanished.

Could it be the same problem despite you are using AMD/ATI graphic card?

Comment: I thought so, I started install of 12.10 and it freezed, so everything was broken. I tried to install from USBStick a fresh 12.10 but it wont start, so I'm still stuck on 12.04 with these freezes :( I will wait for official release of 12.10 on end of October